# How do I write to stdin (returned from exec_command) in paramiko?

Tags: python, unix, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to write to a custom program's stdin with paramiko. Here is a minimal (non-)working example:

~/stdin_to_file.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import time, sys
f = open('/home/me/LOG','w')
while True:
    sys.stdin.flush()
    data = sys.stdin.read()
    f.write(data+'\n\n')
    f.flush()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Then I do these commands in IPython:

```
import paramiko
s = paramiko.client.SSHClient 
s.load_system_host_keys()
s.connect('myserver')
stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command('/home/me/stdin_to_file.py')
stdin.write('Hello!')
stdin.flush()
```

Unfortunately, nothing then appears in ~/LOG. However, if I do

```
$ ~/stdin_to_file.py < some_other_file
```

The contents of some_other_file appear in ~/LOG.

Can anyone suggest where I've gone wrong? It seems like I'm doing the logical thing. None of these work either:

```
stdin.channel.send('hi')
using the get_pty parameter
sending the output of cat - to stdin_to_file.py
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sys.stdin.read()` will keep reading until EOF so in your paramiko script you need to close the `stdin` (returned from `exec_command()`). But how?

#### 1. `stdin.close()` would not work.

According to Paramiko's doc (**v1.16**):

> **Warning:** To correctly emulate the file object created from a socket’s `makefile()` method, a `Channel` and its `ChannelFile` should be able to be closed or garbage-collected independently. **Currently, closing the `ChannelFile` does nothing but *flush* the buffer.**

#### 2. `stdin.channel.close() also has problem.`

Since *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* all share one single channel, `stdin.channel.close()` will also close *stdout* and *stderr* which is not expected.

#### 3. `stdin.channel.shutdown_write()`

The correct solution is to use `stdin.channel.shutdown_write()` which disallows writing to the channel but still allows reading from the channel so `stdout.read()` and `stderr.read()` would still work.

---

See following example to see the difference between `stdin.channel.close()` and `stdin.channel.shutdown_write()`.

```
[STEP 101] # cat foo.py
import paramiko, sys, time

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )
ssh.connect(hostname='127.0.0.1', username='root', password='password')
cmd = "sh -c 'read v; sleep 1; echo $v'"
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
if sys.argv[1] == 'close':
    stdin.write('hello world\n')
    stdin.flush()
    stdin.channel.close()
elif sys.argv[1] == 'shutdown_write':
    stdin.channel.send('hello world\n')
    stdin.channel.shutdown_write()
else:
    raise Exception()
sys.stdout.write(stdout.read() )
[STEP 102] # python foo.py close           # It outputs nothing.
[STEP 103] # python foo.py shutdown_write  # This works fine.
hello world
[STEP 104] #
```

Comment: The key point is that read() reads until EOF. Either I needed to close stdin - which is a rather permanent solution - or I needed to use stdin.read(N) where N <= the length of the data. I opted for the latter.

Comment: added a simple example to show the diff between close() and shutdown_write().

Comment: On python3, sys.stdout.write(stdout.read() ) needs .decode() to work, it should be sys.stdout.write(stdout.read().decode() ) or it will raise `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`